# How to program a double tap action in Android?

Tags: android

View_B is implemented to listen double tap action. In View_A, I need to send a double tap action to View_B.

How to send a double tap action by code ??

Thanks.

Comment: In View_A, what action is being performed that you want to initiate the double tap action of View_B?

Comment: i don't understand your question please give any example.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a time_before before the tap, and the another time_after after tap/taps.
if time_after - time_before less than certain value, it might be a double tap.